# ASP.NET MVC The data doesnt come to controller from partial view used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have main view and main model.

Inside this view i have such lines

```
 foreach (var loadTask in Model.LoadTasks)
 {
     Html.RenderPartial("TripUpdateTask", new TripUpdateTaskModel { Task = loadTask });
 }
```

So in main model i have the

```
  public List<OrderTaskRecord> LoadTasks { get; set; }
```

Submodel is:

```
public class TripUpdateTaskModel
{
    public OrderTaskRecord Task { get; set; }
}
```

I played and played but still unable to save the data. Here is current and simple look.

```
<tr>    
    <td>Actual Time:</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Task.Task.ActualTime)</td>
</tr>
```

In raw html these time controls have same name and same id. So i dont know what need to do to save that.

I mean the data entered on main view back to controller fine, but not from partial view

I use Html.BeginForm and fieldset in main view like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("TripUpdate", "SupplierBookingUpdate", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SupplierBookingUpdateSave" }))
 {
    <fieldset>
    .. table
    </fieldset>
 }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to set the name of the textboxes?

Comment: I want to ask how to save data from partial view. what i need to redo in the code. because entered values not saved to main model

Comment: Do you mean: when they come back in your controller?

Comment: yes.. this is the problem. data entered on main view back to controller fine, but not from partial view

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You should edit your question to reflect your last comment above, since it's not apparent in your question text what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to name each text box individually, I would recommend to bind your collection of `OrderTaskRecord`. That way you do not need to worry about a number of text boxes and their names.

There's a good introduction from [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) on the subject.

You can also try another example here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a custom name to the `input` being generated use this. It passes the html attributes to the `TextBoxFor` method:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Task.Task.ActualTime, new { Name = "yourName" )
```

Of course, you can create counters, etc in here to keep them unique.

You can extract them later in your Controller by getting the Form data:

```
Request.Form["yourName"];
```

Comment: I want to ask how to save data from partial view. what i need to redo in the code. because entered values not saved to main model

Comment: Do you think this is good idea ? i already have 4 fields for each item in collection. And 10 items now. This is 40 controls

Comment: Maybe you can iterate the names and check them to add them to a specific class of yours?

Comment: Didn't understand you. I just was sure Microsoft has something to save data from partial view. As for RequestForm, this is possible as workaround, i just checked. But if there is more elegant solution - i will be happy to hear

Comment: True, but it is very hard to do this automatically when creating the form dynamically. I supposed you had another model already in your action.